# Android SQLite insert in loop issue

Tags: android, sqlite

I have android application which interacts with SQLite database. When I insert data model objects into my database, I have strange issue: on the first iteration nothing is inserted! But second, third, ... iterations processed fine!

Code that creates data model objects:

```
public void initPlannedTape() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        try {
            // init variables for dataResource object here, removed just for brevity
            DataResource dataResource = new DataResource(date, R.color.caldroid_green_planned);
            this.dataSource.addDataResource(dataResource);              
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);  
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

here `dataSource` is object of class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`, its method `addDataResource` is below:

```
public void addDataResource(DataResource dataResource) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DatabaseConstants.DATE_COLUMN, dataResource.getDate());
    values.put(DatabaseConstants.RESOURCE_COLUMN, dataResource.getResource());

    db.insert(DatabaseConstants.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

Why the first iteration doesn't insert object into database?

Comment: by putting log you can find whether first record is able to reach to your addDataSource method or it exit just before that with any exception

Comment: I debugged method addDataResource and it works fine without any problems, exceptions, etc. But the first object isn't inserted...

Comment: Log the return value of insert call. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29

Comment: row id is correct value (not -1), I already checked it in debug

Comment: If its value is -1 which means value is inserted... How you are checking the db whether first is inserted or not ?

Comment: I found the issue, it was my mistake :)
I tried to get all records with the following code
`if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {`
do-while construction fixed this mistake, Faisal, thank you for tip :)